# How do I test if the <T> in Enumerable<T> implements an interface, if <T> is dynamic?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable

I have a method that accepts an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Is there a way to test the dynamic type inside the method to see whether or not it implements a particular interface?

My intention is something like this:

```
public void myMethod(IEnumerable<dynamicT> enumerable)
{
    if (dynamicT is IInterface)
    {
        // do one thing
    }
    else if (dynamicT is IAnotherInterface)
    {
        // do another thing
    }
}
```

**Update**

I should have included this important fact: `<T>` is dynamic.

Please forgive, it's approaching midnight from where I'm coding. :-$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` keyword is for an ***object*** while ***reflection*** is needed for a ***type***:

You can use `typeof(T).GetInterfaces()` to pull all the interfaces applied to a particular Type.

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    var typeInterfaces = typeof(T).GetInterfaces();

    if (typeInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IInterface))) {
        // Something
    }
    else if(typeInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IAnotherInterface))) {
        // Something Else
    }
}
```

**============ Update Based on Comment ============**

If T is ***dynamic*** you cannot get the information you're looking for from the Type itself since T is could represent any number of ***different types*** all at the same time.

You can however loop through each element and test the object itself using the `is` keyword.

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    foreach (var dynObj in enumerable)
    {
        var typeInterfaces = dynObj.GetType().GetInterfaces();

        if (typeInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IInterface))) {
            // Something
        }
        else if(typeInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IAnotherInterface))) {
            // Something Else
        }
    }
}
```

**Or if you just want to test all possible interfaces in the enumerable you could do this:**

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    var allInterfaces = enumerable.SelectMany(e => e.GetType().GetInterfaces()).ToList();

    if (allInterfaces.Contains(typeof(ITheFirstInterface)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Has The First Interface");
    }

    if (allInterfaces.Contains(typeof(ITheSecondInterface)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Has The Second Interface");
    }
}
```

Comment: Jay, Thanks for your answer, which would have resolved the question as originally written. Unfortunately I left out a really important bit of info, that the T was dynamic. So I'm thinking this won't work for my situation.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox I've updated my post with notes and a potential solution for your dynamic problem.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Updated with a 3rd solution as I thought about it a bit more.

Comment: Anyone coming here should also check out @wdosanjos answer also

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox You can rework my second example with the foreach loop to use IsAssignableFrom instead easily. wdosanjos's response is incomplete, it will throw a null ref exception if the list is empty.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> Determines whether an instance of the current Type can be assigned from an instance of the specified Type.

```
public void myMethod(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
    {
        // do one thing
    }
    else if (typeof(IAnotherInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
    {
        // do another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, which perfectly resolved the question as I wrote it. Unfortunately I left out a really important bit of info, that the T was dynamic.

Comment: What results do you expect? Can you provide sample input/output?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.  Since, `T` is dynamic you need to peek the first item in the list to find out its type.

```
public void myMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    dynamic peek = enumerable.FirstOrDefault();
    Type dtype = peek.GetType();

    if (typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(dtype))
    {
        // do one thing
    }
    else if (typeof(IAnotherInterface).IsAssignableFrom(dtype))
    {
        // do another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I ended up using jay's answer above, but I like the use of IsAssignableFrom.